# Google Drive menu invisible after first use (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

After upgrading to Windows 10, the Google Drive menu always shows only one time, then it becomes invisible (but is still functional).

Clicking the triangle icon in the Task bar shows normally a list of files that get or got synced, and there is a three-dot menu on top right, where you can chose 'Exit' or 'Settings', and such.
That works fine; but after I do something else and come back, the second time that display is hidden/invisible. it is still fully functional - if I move the mouse, mouse-overs come up for the currently syncing files, and if I click the place where the menu is (guessing from memory), the sub-menu comes up and I can 'Exit Google Drive' and such. After I kill googledrivesync.exe, and start it again, it works again - once. Same after reboot; it works - once.

All other functionality is fine - it logs me in, syncs, etc. - it is just a nuisance to not know when syncing is done, and having to find the exit button blindly if I want to close it.

The menu is not behind any other window; I closed all others to be sure.

I did not find anything when googling.

[image: This is the display on the first time - afterwards, it's invisible]

(no, I did not use the 'Quit' - I just click anywhere outside, and it becomes invisible/transparent)

Answer (score 5):

While this bug still persists, I have found that once you click the drive icon, you can invoke the Setting button's menu by pressing the ENTER key. It is useful for quitting the app or reaching the preferences.

Also, try to disable/enable Wifi. When I switch Wifi connection, google drive says that is cannot connect and on that moment (before connection is made) I can click the faded icon and the menu/widget/whatever will be shown correctly and it will continue syncing as it establishes a connection and it will be shown till you click outside.

ALSO, if you're using a laptop you can click the drive icon and close/open the physical lid of laptop. This shows me the menu when screen comes back on. Can't figure out how to do it on the PC though.

Comment: Yep, <kbd>Ret</kbd> works. That certainly helps a lot, thanks.

Comment: Confirming you can hit Enter and the menu becomes visible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I normally fix it like this:

- open up TaskManager [<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and then start task manager],
- click more details,
- find google drive,
- click on it [there might be two, click the one with the highest network usage value],
- click end task.

that is like clicking on the dots and quitting drive!

then I open drive back up for the start menu and repeat the process 3 times, at the thir time it usually works fine!

Comment: This makes me nervous because there are two Drive process listed, and we don't know what might be messed up terminating them randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem – everything works fine but there is no the familiar yellow-blue-green Triangle on the task bar. I just discovered that there is a new icon that looks like a cloud with and up-arrow inside. That is a “backup and sync” process icon. I think this is the old “Google Drive” process icon.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue - I couldn't reach the menu of "Backup and sync from Google" that usually appears on the Left or Right-click on its icon in the tray.

Magically it appeared after I tried hitting ENTER key right after mouse clicking on the icon.

But then inner menus are still grayed-out.

Killing of the "googledrivesync.exe" processes and then launching Backup and Sync finally helped.

UPD: Today I have uncovered that the menu sometimes appear but it us under all other windows, so if you minimize everything before clicking the tray icon - there is a chance to "catch" the menu there :)